# SQL Server, Maintenance Plan, Shrinking DATA File

Tags: sql-server, shrink

After 5 years of work on our Sql Server database, I plan to carry out a maintenance on, and we plan to eliminate more than 170 GB of useless data by truncating some tables, and after that a Shrink File operation will also be carried out, and when I checked on SQL Server I found this:

Allocated Space: 713912.31 MB 
Free Space Available: 710979.13 MB (99%).

Is that normal ? or we have some issue behind this ?
Is their some bad configuration that we have made ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: How did you get your sizing information for your objects and for your database? There's obviously a discrepancy in the expected size of data to be eliminated vs your reported space usage.

Answer (score 1):

> Is that normal ?

It just shows you have much free space you have in that file.
From looking at this it would mean you only have +-3GB of data.

Without doing any shrink operations, SQL will never give you the disk space back, so if you have a database that grows to 713GB and you archive all of it, the file size will still be 713GB until you shrink.

If this is the correct database you're looking at, the estimation of cleaning 160GB would be impossible though, since there's not that much left to clean.
You can however reclaim that disk space if you want.

Be careful with shrinking often, it can have a performance impact over time.
In this case though if you have a 99% empty file a shrink operation is fine.

Why the file is almost empty is not something we can possibly answer. Either you had data in there that is no longer there, or you initialized a file that is way too big, but that would just be guessing for us.

EDIT:
Run below query, this will give you a result per file of how much free space you have, let us know what the result of this is.
Make sure to replace/mask the file names you don't want to disclose on the internet.

```
CREATE TABLE #FileSize
(dbName NVARCHAR(128), 
    FileName NVARCHAR(128), 
    type_desc NVARCHAR(128),
    CurrentSizeMB DECIMAL(10,2), 
    FreeSpaceMB DECIMAL(10,2)
);
    
INSERT INTO #FileSize(dbName, FileName, type_desc, CurrentSizeMB, FreeSpaceMB)
exec sp_msforeachdb 
'use [?]; 
 SELECT DB_NAME() AS DbName, 
        name AS FileName, 
        type_desc,
        size/128.0 AS CurrentSizeMB,  
        size/128.0 - CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name, ''SpaceUsed'') AS INT)/128.0 AS FreeSpaceMB
FROM sys.database_files
WHERE type IN (0,1);';
    
SELECT * 
FROM #FileSize
```

Comment: Hi Yannick,

Thank you for your response and your analysis, however regarding:

The file is almost empty, I don't think so because we even have 5 years of work on the system.
data which is no longer there. This is not the case because no archiving or data processing has been carried out. Initialized a file that is much too large perhaps yes because a Server Migration was recently carried out and perhaps this is where the problem occurred,
The question now arises, is it normal that these data of allocated space and free space are represented as such.

Comment: See my edit @MohammedAmineBENAMARA

Comment: Dear Yannick, Thanks for the update.
After running the script provided I received the following result:     CurrentSiezMB : 785303.56   FreeSpaceMB: 70865.88   
I noticed that the free space information is different from that provided by sql server when I used the shrink operation wizard,  which it It always shows me that I have 99% free space.

Comment: Maybe add some screenshots of the things you're looking at, that query should always return more than 1 row as it also checks all system databases AND all log and data files. So even if you're looking at 1 database, you should have 2 results.

Comment: Hi @yannick. Yes, you are right, but I preferred to give the result directly and only for the DATA File so as not to publish all the data on the NET. But if you see it necessary to publish a screenshot I will do so without problem.